# How do I set AutoFilter when building XML with StringBuilder in C# for Excel?

Tags: c#, xml, excel, excel-2007, autofilter

I'm not using any third-party libraries like EPPlus or the OpenXml spec. I'm not exporting HTML or a GridView for my datasource. I am not using VBA. I am reading data from a DataTable and building the string representation of the xml that represents the data and saving it as an .XLS file. The problem is that I can't seem to get `<AutoFilter />` to work in any way that I've been able to find so far:

- Added `<autoFilter ref=\"A1:D33\"></autoFilter>` just before the closing  tag.
- Added `<AutoFilter ref=\"A1:D33\"></AutoFilter>` just before the closing  tag.
- Added `<autoFilter ref=\"A1:D1\"></autoFilter>` just before the closing  tag.
- Added `<AutoFilter ref=\"A1:D1\"></AutoFilter>` just before the closing  tag.
- Added `<AllowFilter />` to `<WorkSheetOptions />` tag.
- Added `ref=\"A1:D33\"` to the `<Table />` tag.
- Added `ref=\"A1:D1\"` to the `<Table />` tag.

I'm not asking for someone to tell me to use some other tool to build this. I am completely comfortable using any number of methods to build Excel outputs, but that is not my requirement for this particular code.

If anyone has a completely working example set of XML that I can copy/pasta I would be ecstatic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by building XML data and saving it to .XLS. As far as I know, that's not doable. Unless you're talking about the "old" version of the Office XML format (the "new" version is Open XML, but you mentioned you're not using that). You also didn't mention where you want the AutoFilter (because there are 2 places, one for the worksheet and one for tables).

So here are a couple of suggestions:

1. If it's for a table, put the autoFilter tag as the first child tag within the table tag.
2. If it's for a worksheet, the autoFilter tag should be after these child tags of worksheet (if present): sheetPr, dimension, sheetViews, sheetFormatPr, cols, sheetData, sheetCalcPr, sheetProtection, protectedRanges, scenarios (and then autoFilter). Those child tags are also the very first set of child tags of worksheet.

Comment: Geez, I had my tags out of order :P